# Rabbitvcs Svn access to this repository is not allowed

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, rabbitvcs

I have a repository on my windows server 2008 R2, using TortoiseSvn. In my repository's **/conf/svnserve** file I've changed:

```
auth-access = write
```

and created a user in **/conf/passwd** file:

```
[users]
p001 = somepassword
```

I run the server via cmd

```
svnserve.exe --daemon --r "path\to\repo"
```

now on my ubuntu using RabbitVcs Svn I can easily checkout the repository using

```
svn//my.ip.to.server
```

but I can't commit, it says **Authorization Failed** which makes sense due to the above setting, but my question is that rabbitvcs doesn't ask for username/password upon commit. Please advice, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You forgot in `conf\svnserve.conf` two things

   #### Uncomment the line below to use the default authorization file.

   authz-db = authz
   ...

   #### Uncomment the line below to use the default password file.

   password-db = passwd
2. In authz-file you **must** to define rule for at least access to `/`, otherwise you'll get error like

   1144 2015-02-18T15:42:17.375000Z 127.0.0.1 u2 repo Authorization Failed read /

in log-file (which I'll recommend to have on debug)

but:

for some reason even with

```
# [/]
u1 = rw
u2 = rw
```

(auth. user can read and write in repo) I got

```
>svn ls svn://localhost/repo
Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3690> Test Repo
Username: u2
Password for 'u2': *****
svn: E170001: Authorization failed
```

for unknown reason

Comment: Thanks Lazy Badger, those config changes did the work and I didn't encounter the problem you've mentioned. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For me it got resolved by restarting the svnserve.exe with "run as administrator"